# How to deal with existing installations with Homebrew?

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Before installing Homebrew, I had existing installations on my MacBook. For instance, I installed Google Chrome and Node.js as people normally do - by visiting their websites and downloading the .dmg/.pkg files.

Whereas, with Homebrew I would have ran

```
brew cask install google-chrome
brew install node
```

To integrate these applications with Homebrew, would I need to uninstall them and reinstall through Homebrew? Can Homebrew detect these existing installations? Is there an advantage to using a package manager?

(My thoughts are migrating them would allow me use `brew update` to maintain them.)

Comment: brew cask cannot and will not update your apps. You can uninstall the apps you have already installed and install them again with brew cask. You will not gain much, though - brew cask makes it easier to install/uninstall apps. It does not update as the standard homebrew does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To integrate these applications with Homebrew, would I need to uninstall them and reinstall through Homebrew?

Yes.

> Can Homebrew detect these existing installations?

Homebrew can’t manage applications that were installed outside of it. It can detect some installations—for example if Python is installed Homebrew won’t force you to install it again if a formula depends on it—but can’t act on them.

> Is there an advantage to using a package manager?

It depends.

- If you already use GUI apps like Google Chrome, uninstalling them then reinstalling with `brew cask` won’t change anything; `brew cask` installs stuff but you have to update it yourself after that.
- If you don’t already have these apps, using a package manager is faster an easier than going on each website, download the `.dmg`s, drag the `.app`s. It’s more automatable and you can use [`brew-bundle`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle) for a faster setup when you get a new machine.
- Regarding classic Homebrew formulae (i.e. stuff installed with `brew install` instead of `brew cask install`) Homebrew *will* update things for you so depending on your usage it might make sense to uninstall then reinstall through Homebrew. In any case `brew install foo` is always faster than searching the Web for the instructions to install `foo`, and most popular formulae are already pre-compiled for the last 3 major OS X releases.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, Homebrew is a Command Line Interface (CLI) for apps such as python etc and Homebrew-Cask (HBC) is an extension of Homebrew allowing the installation of GUI apps from the CLI.

At present there is no provision for updates using HBC so i have written scripts that take of some issues.

The scripts will create a file that lists the files to be updated including apps that are defined as latest. You can then modify the file to suit your requirements and install updates using my olinst script.

For more information visit my github.

https://github.com/pacav69/homebrew-homebrew-caskroom-offline-installer